# Problems installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I own a Dell Inspiron 15-5558, wich has a Nvidia 920m and the integrated intel graphics. I already followed lots of guides on how to install nvidia drivers, needless to say none of them worked. When i try to boot after installing the drivers, all i get is a black screen right after the gnome loading screen. I wonder if it has something to do with the optimus stuff, but since the gnome screen does show up for a little time i have no idea. Any help is welcome :)

I'm running Ubuntu gnome 16.04

Comment: I see no problem in reinstalling ubuntu if it makes things easier since it's a fresh install anyway. So the "right way" of installing the nvidia drivers would be already awesome.

Answer (score 3):

#### First remove all currently installed NVIDIA software.

In the GRUB boot menu, select the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

#### Install the drivers supporting NVIDIA GEFORCE 920M.

In the GRUB boot menu, select the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note: Leave a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.
After the NVIDIA drivers are installed, adding the boot parameter is not necessary any more.
Switch between Intel and NVIDIA graphics with NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles.